# Не проходит миграция class AddAttachmentImageToPhotos

Tags: ruby-on-rails, migrate

Запускаю:

```
rails generate paperclip photo image
```

создается файл `20220707091655_add_attachment_image_to_photos.rb`

```
class AddAttachmentImageToPhotos < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def self.up
    change_table :photos do |t|
      t.attachment :image
    end
  end

  def self.down
    remove_attachment :photos, :image
  end
end
```

далее запускаю `rake db:migrate`, выдает ошибку:

```
rake aborted!
StandardError: Directly inheriting from ActiveRecord::Migration is not supported. Please specify the Active Record release the migration was written for:

  class AddAttachmentImageToPhotos < ActiveRecord::Migration[7.0]
/home/rs8/RS_New/db/migrate/20220707091655_add_attachment_image_to_photos.rb:1:in `<main>'

Caused by:
StandardError: Directly inheriting from ActiveRecord::Migration is not supported. Please specify the Active Record release the migration was written for:

  class AddAttachmentImageToPhotos < ActiveRecord::Migration[7.0]
/home/rs8/RS_New/db/migrate/20220707091655_add_attachment_image_to_photos.rb:1:in `<main>'
Tasks: TOP => db:migrate
(See full trace by running task with --trace)
```

Answer (score 0):

Вам нужно указать версию `ActiveRecord::Migration`, от которой наследуется ваша миграция. Paperclip последний раз обновлялся 4 года назад, тогда не было необходимости в этом, поэтому автоматически она указана не была. Версия совпадает с версией рельс и указывается в квадратных скобках после имени класса

```
class AddAttachmentImageToPhotos < ActiveRecord::Migration[7.0]
```

Comment: Все равно выдаёт ошибку (((

Comment: Такую же, как и раньше?

Comment: == 20220714071717 AddAttachmentImageToPhotos: migrating =======================
-- change_table(:photos)
rake aborted!
StandardError: An error has occurred, this and all later migrations canceled:

wrong number of arguments (given 3, expected 2)
/home/rs8/RS_New/db/migrate/20220714071717_add_attachment_image_to_photos.rb:4:in `block in up'
/home/rs8/RS_New/db/migrate/20220714071717_add_attachment_image_to_photos.rb:3:in `up'

Comment: Caused by:
ArgumentError: wrong number of arguments (given 3, expected 2)
/home/rs8/RS_New/db/migrate/20220714071717_add_attachment_image_to_photos.rb:4:in `block in up'
/home/rs8/RS_New/db/migrate/20220714071717_add_attachment_image_to_photos.rb:3:in `up'
Tasks: TOP => db:migrate
(See full trace by running task with --trace)

Comment: Paperclip же больше не поддерживается и с седьмыми рельсами он вообще не умеет работать - https://github.com/thoughtbot/paperclip/issues/2698. Вот рабочий форк https://github.com/kreeti/kt-paperclip. Или использовать встроенный ActiveStorage, что пожалуй даже проще

Comment: Спасибо, через kt-paperclip всё заработало.